# MongoDB find in one query records created in last week and since always

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to build a query that return a total count of users and a count of users created on **last week**.
There's a field called **timeStamp** that represents the date of creation.

I'm trying to do this with aggregation, I guess I should first group all users by **timeStamp** but then I don't know exactly what could I do to achieve this.

**EDIT**:
Sample user document:

```
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("57be35d6fab7762415376b1b"),
   "provider" : "local",
   "isValidAccount" : true,
   "isActive" : true,
   "timeStamp" : ISODate("2016-08-25T00:03:34.533Z"),
   "scope" : "getm-user",
   "tkbSponsor" : "example@example.com",
   "userId" : "example@example.com",
   "passwd" : "$2a$14$WARJLD4RtYOApJvTNwQHluLvWpZzQzvUxudIln.j5aQJaxYsJtHEG",
   "posFavorites" : [ ],
```

}

What I do need is a count of ALL users and another count of all users created 7 days ago.

Comment: Could you please add the sample document and expected result in the post?

Comment: I just added a sample document

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to create a date range query that satisfy the given condition of users created last week, this means defining two variables that will hold the date objects representing the start of the day last week and the end. You will need this to query your collection later on in the pipeline.

You can start with the **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline step that groups all the documents in the collection and calculates the total docs using **[`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#grp._S_sum)**. You can also calculate the conditional sum based on the date range using the **[`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#exp._S_cond)** tenary operator to feed the **[`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#grp._S_sum)**.

The following explains the above approach:

```
var today = new Date();
var lastWeekStart = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate() - 7);
var lastWeekEnd = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate() - 7);
var start = new Date(lastWeekStart.setHours(0,0,0,0));
var end = new Date(lastWeekEnd.setHours(23,59,59,999));

db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": null,
            "total": { "$sum": 1 },
            "usersCreatedLastWeek": {
                "$sum": {
                    "$cond": [
                        { 
                            "$and": [
                                { "$gte": [ "$timeStamp", start ] },
                                { "$lte": [ "$timeStamp", end ] }
                            ]
                        },
                        1,
                        0
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Answer (score 2):

Users created last week: timeStamps with week equal to last calendar week.

After declaring today's date. we can use aggregation stages in a pipeline like so:

1. Project to get time stamp's year and week, and also current year and week.
2. Project again to compare :

   - current year with time stamp's year.
   - current week(-1) with time stamp's week.
3. Match comparison fields with 0, as 0 means equal.
4. Lastly group to get total of such time stamps of last week.

Execute this on mongo shell :

```
var today = new Date();
db.yourCollectionName.aggregate([{
    $project: {
        "tsYear": {$year: "$timeStamp"},
        "tsWeek": {$week: "$timeStamp"},
        "todYear": {$year: today},
        "todWeek": {$week: today}
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        cmpWeek: {$cmp: ['$tsWeek', {$add: [-1, '$todWeek']}]}, 
        cmpYear: {$cmp: ['$tsYear', '$todYear']}
    }
}, {
    $match: {
        cmpWeek: 0,
        cmpYear: 0
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: "UsersCreated", 
        totalLastWeek: {$sum: 1}
    }
}
])
```